# Understanding regex criteria in pattern match

Tags: regex

I am trying to determine what the following pattern match criteria allows me to enter:

```
\s*([\w\.-]+)\s*=\s*('[^']*'|"[^"]*"|[^\s]+)
```

From my attempt to decipher (by looking at the regex's I do understand) it seems to say I can start with any character sequence then I must have a brace followed by alphanumerics, then another sequence followed by braces, one intial single quote, no backslashes closed by a brace ???

Sorry if I have got this completely muddled. Any help is appreciated.

Regards,
Pablo

Comment: You should replace `[^\s]+` by `[^\s>]+`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The square brackets are character classes, and the parens are for grouping. I'm not sure what you mean by "braces".

This basically matches a name=value pair where than name consists of one or more "word", dot or hyphen characters, and the value is either a single quoted character or a double-quoted string of characters, or a bunch of non-whitespace characters. Single-quoted characters cannot contain a single quote, and double quoted strings may not contain double-quotes (both arguably minor flaws whatever syntax this is from). There's also arguably some ambiguity since the last option ("a bunch on non-whitespace characters") could match something starting with a single or double quote.

Also, zero or more whitespaces may appear around the equal sign or at the beginning (that's the `\s*` bits).

Comment: It looks like a crude attempt to pluck an *attribute=value* sequence out of an HTML tag.  If that's the case, I would change the last alternative to `[^\s>]+`.  Aside from that it will probably work 99+% of the time, simplistic though it is.

Answer (score 1):

It's looking for strings of text which are basically

```
<identifier> = <value>
```

- *identifier* is made up of letters, digits, '-' and '.'
- *value* can be a single-quoted strings, double-quoted strings, or any other sequence of characters (as long as it doesn't contain a space).

So it would match lines that look like this:

```
foo = 1234
bar-bar= "a double-quoted string"
bar.foo-bar ='a single quoted string'
   .baz      =stackoverflow.com this part is ignored
```

Some things to note:

- There's no way to put a quote inside a quoted string (such as using \" inside "...").
- Anything after the quoted string is ignored.
- If a quoted string isn't used for *value*, then everything from the first space onwards is ignored.
- Whitespace is optional

Answer (score 0):

[RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) says:

```
\s*([\w\.-]+)\s*=\s*('[^']*'|"[^"]*"|[^\s]+)

Options: case insensitive

Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.) «\s*»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «([\w\.-]+)»
   Match a single character present in the list below «[\w\.-]+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
      A word character (letters, digits, etc.) «\w»
      A . character «\.»
      The character “-” «-»
Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.) «\s*»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
Match the character “=” literally «=»
Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.) «\s*»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «('[^']*'|"[^"]*"|[^\s]+)»
   Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «'[^']*'»
      Match the character “'” literally «'»
      Match any character that is NOT a “'” «[^']*»
         Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
      Match the character “'” literally «'»
   Or match regular expression number 2 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «"[^"]*"»
      Match the character “"” literally «"»
      Match any character that is NOT a “"” «[^"]*»
         Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
      Match the character “"” literally «"»
   Or match regular expression number 3 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «[^\s]+»
      Match a single character that is a “non-whitespace character” «[^\s]+»
         Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»


Created with RegexBuddy
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us break `\s*([\w\.-]+)\s*=\s*('[^']*'|\"[^\"]*\"|[^\s]+)` apart:

`\s*([\w\.-]+)\s*`:

- `\s*` means 0 or more whitespace characters
- `[\w.-]+ means 1 or more of the following characters: A-Za-z0-9_.-

`('[^']*'|\"[^\"]*\"|[^\s]+)`:

- One or more characters non-' characters enclosed in ' and '.
- One or more characters non-" characters enclodes in " and ".
- One or more characters not containing a space

So basically, you can mostly ignore the `\s*`'s in trying to understand the expression, they just handle removing spacing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have got it completely muddled. :P  For one thing, there are no braces in that regex; that word usually refers to the curly brackets: `{}`.  That regex only contains square brackets and parentheses (aka round brackets), and they're all regex metacharacters--they aren't meant to match those characters literally.  The same goes for most of the other characters.

You might find [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) useful.  Very good tutorial and reference site for all things regex.